# sys.argv[1]. IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find out the similarity between 2 images but I'm getting this error

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  img1 = sys.argv[0]
  img2 = sys.argv[1]

  # Create image objects
  image1 = Image.open(img1)
  image2 = Image.open(img2)

  # Test pixel by pixel
  get_image_pixel_similarity(img1, img2)
```

> sys.argv[1]. IndexError: list index out of range

How can I sort out my problem?

Comment: What is the command you typed to launch your script ?

Comment: How do you run the script? Also: sys.argv[0] is the script's name; you need sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2].

Answer (score 0):

Th command you type must be:

```
python script.py img1 img2
```

Then, you have to use:

```
img1 = sys.argv[1]
img2 = sys.argv[2]
```

I suggest you do this in one line:

```
img1, img2 = sys.argv[1:2]
```

argv is a list that start with the script name.

Comment: If `1` is out of range then  `1:` is even more out of range ...

Comment: Or `img1, img3 = sys.argv[1:2]` to evade issues if there are not 2 items in `sys.argv`.